# Best practices to define constants used in an app

Tags: java, android, constants

I have a ContentProvider in a *provider* package where a JOIN query is declared:

```
final String ALL_DATA_FOR_AN_ANIMAL = "SELECT " +
        "animals._id, "
        + COLUMN_NAME + " AS _name, "
        + COLUMN_CLASSE + " AS _class, "
        + "IFNULL(" + COLUMN_OVERRIDE_INDIVIDU_NUMBER + ", " +  COLUMN_INDIVIDU_NUMBER + ")"  + " AS _ind_nb, "
        + "FROM " + ANIMALS_TABLE_NAME + " LEFT JOIN " + ANIMALS_OVERRIDE_TABLE_NAME
        + " ON " + COLUMN_NAME + " = " + COLUMN_OVERRIDE_NAME
        + " WHERE animals._id = ?";
```

All the sql aliases defined with AS are used in a ContentResolver (in an *operations* package) to define projection and selection passed to the query in the ContentProvider

```
String[] projection = new String[]{"_name", "_class", "_ind_nb", "_in_danger"};
String selection = "_id";
String[] selectionArgs = {selectionArg};

return mCr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Finally the aliases are used to display the result of the query in the *view* package

```
        tv_Name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_name")));
        tv_Class.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_class")));
        //...
```

I think it would be better to define the aliases inside a *Constants* class instead of using hard-coded Strings, but I already have some constants declared for the ui in a package *ui.utils*.

What are the best practices? Is it better to write one *Constants* class pro package or to write a single *Constants* class for the entire app ? (.. or using these aliases through different package is a sign of bad architecture?)

**update**

Below is the *Constants* class I implemented for the gui, this class is in the package *view.utils*

```
public class Constants {
    public static final int ANIMAL_PAGE_POS = 0;
    public static final int CARACTERISTICS_PAGE_POS = 1;
    //...
}
```

I would do the same for the aliases, something like:

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String ALIAS_ID = "_id";
    public static final String ALIAS_NAME = "_name";
    //...
}
```

The questions are:

- is it a good solution to share variables (specifically aliases) across different packages?
- (if answer to first question is yes) do I have to create multiple Constants-like class or is it a good practices to define all constants for all package inside a single Constants class?

Comment: so you want to use non-editable strings?

Comment: If yes, set them to final. `public static final String ...`

Comment: You can write a Provider contract with all column names and methods to generate URIs for your provider and use [this lib](https://github.com/reinaldoarrosi/QueryBuilder) or something similar to generate queries

Comment: `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_name"))` sounds like `cursor.getString("_name")` or `cursor.getString(XXX_NAME)` whose safer alternative would be `record.getName()`.

Comment: This question [Storing configs in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883186/storing-configs-in-android/37883928) can be helpful for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One thing I forgot to say it that I defined a class Contract where all tables are defined. As @Sourabh suggested I used this class to define the constants I need for the JOIN query

```
public static final class JoinEntry implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String COLUMN_JOIN_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_JOIN_CLASS = "_class";
    public static final String COLUMN_JOIN_SUB_CLASS = "_sub_class";
    public static final String COLUMN_JOIN_NB_IND = "_ind_nb";
}
```

Comment: This should be an edit to the original question, not an answer. And definitely should not be the accepted answer as it does not actually answer anything.